# Error while compiling [Warning] multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]

Tags: c

I'm trying to compile the following the program but I'm facing two errors:

1. multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
2. overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int age;
    float weight;
    char gender;

    age = 23;
    weight = 60.5;
    gender = 'M ';

    printf("Persons Profile \n\n\n Age: %i,\n\nweight: %f,\n\nGender: %c",age,weight,gender);

    getch();    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change `gender='M ';` to `gender='M';`. The former character literal consist of two characters (space is also a character) while the latter character literal consist of one character.

Answer (score 2):

The `gender` variable is of `type` `char`. 
`char`in C represents the character type, suitable for storing a simple character—traditionally one from the [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) encoding. More recently, UTF-8 encoded characters are common. The char type can also store small integers and is technically an integer type.

In your code `gender` variable contains two characters `M` and (space). If you remove the `space` it will remove both of your mentioned errors.

Change `gender = 'M ';` 
To `gender = 'M';`

For further C assistance http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming